# "See more text" in Angular/PrimeNg

Tags: javascript, angular, css, typescript, primeng

Please guide me achieve "see more text" functionality.

I work on angular 4 and primgNg. My page shows a column named "Description". Initially I have to show only 1000 characters in the that column and show a `down arrow`, if the description is more than 1000 characters. On click of the `down arrow` the para will expand and it will show full text and the arrow turns to the `up arrow`. In other words, toggling. Please guide me achieve this. So far I tried as below but unable to achieve the requirement.

HTML

```
<div>Description</div>
<div>{{details.desc | slice:0:1000}}</div>
<div *ngIf="details.desc.length >= 1000">
  <span class="arrow-down"></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-down {
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;

  border-top: 10px solid #f00;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just created working example based on your code [here on StackBlitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gx4yag)

but better solution is to make it as directive and reuse.

hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

`seeMore` is a boolean.

```html
<span>
   {{
     seeMore
     ? project.descriptions
     : project.descriptions.slice(0, -5)
   }}
</span>
<span *ngIf="project.descriptions.length > 5"
      (click)="seeMore = !seeMore">
   {{ !seeMore ? "See More" : "See Less" }}
</span>
```